# Is there any way to pass a whole model via html.actionlink in ASP.NET MVC 3 razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reply", "BlogReplyCommentAdd", "Blog",
     new { blogPostId = blogPostId, replyblogPostmodel = Model,
     captchaValid = Model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha },null)
```

My Controller :

```
public ActionResult BlogReplyCommentAdd(int blogPostId, BlogPostModel model, bool captchaValid)
{}
```

In my Controller i am passing whole model.But values of properties are null till reach to Action

BlogPostModel:

```
  [Validator(typeof(BlogPostValidator))]
public partial class BlogPostModel : BaseNopEntityModel
{
    public BlogPostModel()
    {
        Tags = new List<string>();
        Comments = new List<BlogCommentModel>();
        AddNewComment = new AddBlogCommentModel();

    }

    public string SeName { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public bool AllowComments { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfComments { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public IList<string> Tags { get; set; }

    public IList<BlogCommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
    public AddBlogCommentModel AddNewComment { get; set; }


}
```

Any how i need whole model.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any exceptions/errors?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Pass the id that you need and then retrieve the model from your data store within your controller. There's no reason to try and pass an entire model object across the wire - that's not how MVC works.

Comment: @levelnis: I don't have repository which gives me detail of Model by ID.Can you provide some example.

Comment: @NetraSW then you need to add that method to the repository.  How can a blog post have an ID but you can't retrieve it from the repository by it's ID?  How do you display a blog post for a particular url?  Is it like the "I'm feeling lucky" button on Google?

Comment: @AndrasZoltan:It is not method its model class.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going about this correct way at all.  The only time whole model data gets passed in the query string like this is when an HTML form is submitted via a GET operation; and even then that's not ideal except in cases where HTTP caching isn't a problem.

In this case, you're already passing the ID of the blog post in the query string to the controller method - so in your controller method you go and retrieve the blog post model and then pass it to the view.

*Edit* Upon adding this answer - @levelnis' comment then showed up - what (s)he's/they've said is exactly the same thing.

**Update**

And think about it - if you make it so that's how your site works - then anybody could 'publish' content on your blog's site by seeding the query string with all sorts of horrible stuff, not to mention making your site a playground for SEO spammers and such.